# Почему не выполняется чтение добавленной строки из MS Access?

Tags: c#, oledb

Я использую универсальный поставщик данных на базе интерфейса. Чтение данных, которые были созданы в MS Access выполняется без проблем. Данные, которые были добавлены через программу, почему то не читаются. Если быть точнее, читаются частично. Например, можно получить количество строк, но прочитать значение по индексу не получается, как будто этих строк нет в БД.
Метод добавления строки:

```
public int AppendRow(string tableName)
{
    IDbCommand cmd = null;
    IDbDataAdapter ida = null;
    int result = 0;

    try
    {
        connection.Open();
        cmd = connection.CreateCommand();
        cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO " + tableName + " DEFAULT VALUES";
        ida = PrvDataAdapter();
        ida.InsertCommand = cmd;
        result = ida.InsertCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Error");
    }
    finally
    {
        if (connection.State == ConnectionState.Open)
            connection.Close();
    }

    cmd.Dispose();
    return result;
}

IDbDataAdapter PrvDataAdapter()
{
    IDbDataAdapter ida = null;

    switch (_provider)
    {
        case Provider.OleDb:
            ida = new OleDbDataAdapter();
            break;
        case Provider.SqlClient:
            ida = new SqlDataAdapter();
            break;
     }

     return ida;
}
```

Метод чтеня целого значения (поле ID):

```
public int GetIntValue(string tableName, int indexColumn, int indexRow)
{
    IDbCommand cmd = null;
    IDataReader idr = null;
    int value = 0;

    try
    {
        connection.Open();
        cmd = connection.CreateCommand();
        cmd.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM " + tableName;
        idr = cmd.ExecuteReader();

        DataTable table = new DataTable();
        table.Load(idr);
        DataColumn column = table.Columns[indexColumn];
        DataRow row = table.Rows[indexRow];

        if (table.Columns[indexColumn].DataType == typeof(int))
        value = (int)row[column];

        idr.Close();
        table.Dispose();
        column.Dispose();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Error");
    }
    finally
    {
        if (connection.State == ConnectionState.Open)
            connection.Close();
    }

    cmd.Dispose();
    idr.Dispose();

    return value;
}
```

По-видимому, метод добавления записи по умолчанию создает некорректные данные. Вопрос, что не так сделано?

Comment: В самом ACCESS'е проверяли наличие вставленных программно данных? Что означает фраза "как будто этих строк нет в БД"? Вылетает исключение OutOfRangeException? Или какова реакция программы на попытку считать вставленные программно строки?

Comment: Да, конечно, в БД Access запись добавляется. Никаких исключений, и даже намека на ошибку. Я проверял на момент отладки, количество строк верное, но значение ячейки не отображается. Причем не важно, для какого именно столбца.

Comment: "Не отображается" - это как? В приведенном примере вы считываете целое значение - оно отсутствовать не может. Что возвращает функция в случае добавленных программно строк? Какое значение вы видите для этой строки в ACCESS? Добавляете то вы DEFAULT VALUES ...

Comment: Например, строка под индексом (2) была добавлена программным путем. Строки с индексом (0-1) были добавлены через интерфейс MS Access 2016 (БД сохраняется в формате 2000-2003 с расширением *.mdb). Когда проходишь под отладчиком, значение свойства `table.Rows` по индексу (2) показывет значение индекса (1), хотя свойство `Count` четко фиксирует общее количество строк "3".

Comment: Кажется я понял в чем причина, значение добавленной строки было записано в индекс (0). С чем это может быть связано? Нужно явно указать индекс?

Comment: Зависит от того, как у вас создана таблица. Если ваш индекс имеет тип Счетчик, то он должен автоматически инкрементироваться, и попытка задать его явно выльется в ошибку. Если же это просто целое число, то вам нужно самостоятельно позаботиться о генерации уникального индекса.

Comment: Это счетчик, и он соответствует индексу строк.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

По-видимому, это оптимальное решение:

```
public int AppendRow(string tableName)
{
    IDbCommand cmd = null;
    int result = 0;

    try
    {
        connection.Open();
        cmd = connection.CreateCommand();
        cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO " + tableName + " DEFAULT VALUES";
        result = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Error");
    }
    finally
    {
        if (connection.State == ConnectionState.Open)
            connection.Close();
    }

    cmd.Dispose();
    return result;
}
```